# Burninate/synonymize tag: definition

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There were six questions tagged "definition". In most cases, it was either being used as a synonym of "terminology" or its only semantic content was "I'm asking about the definition of something or other", which doesn't make sense as a tag. (It's a type of question, rather than a subject.)

I've already removed the tag from all the questions it was used on.  Can it please be burninated, or maybe made into a synonym of "terminology"?

Comment: Good catch, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that there are no questions with the tag, it will disappear from the list of tags overnight.

Moderators can make it a synonym of [terminology](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) but I don't see a compelling reason to do so.

Stack Exchange staff can blacklist it, but they'll want more evidence of misuse than 6 occurrences (it was introduced in [87051](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87051/does-big-oh-notation-in-optimization-follow-the-same-convention-as-in-cs) as far as I can tell).

Comment: I agree there's no strong reason to make the synonym and definitely no reason to blacklist.